# Cheerio get content including the breaks and H tags from .text()

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

Is there a way to output the text from html using Cheerio which includes some html tags? I know that the `.html()` outputs the full html, but I only want the text using `.text()` but with all H tags and breaks?

Example:

```html
<div class="className"><h1>Something here</h1></br><p>Next line text</p></div>
```

Should output:

```html
<h1>Something here</h1></br>Next line text
```

Code what I have now:

```js
const $ = await fetchHTML(thisEntry.link);
const content = $(`div[class='${feedDiv}']`).text()
```

Which only outputs the text of the div without any alinea breaks or H1 tags. The `.text()` outputs also `<img>` tags by default.

**UPDATE**
I am trying to do a trimmed function as discussed in the comments, but still not working... Am I overlooking something?

```js
async function fetchHTML(url) {
    const { data } = await axios.get(url);
    return cheerio.load(data, { decodeEntities: false });
}

async function createFeed(feedConfig, entries) {
const $ = await fetchHTML(thisEntry.link);

        $(function () {
            function clean(o, h) {
                var results = '';
                if (h == undefined) {
                    results = o.text().trim();
                } else {
                    $(o)
                        .children()
                        .each(function (i, el) {
                            if (h.indexOf($(el).prop('nodeName').toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                                console.log('Found', $(el).prop('nodeName'));
                                results += $(el).prop('outerHTML');
                            } else {
                                console.log($(el).text().trim());
                                results += $(el).text().trim();
                            }
                        });
                }
                return results;
            }

            $(".className").html(clean($(".className"), ["h1", "br"]));
        });

console.log($.text().trim());
}
```

Console outputs nothing

Comment: Are all items wrapped with HTML?

Comment: Probably you want some kind o regex solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own Trim style function. Feed in the object and the Elements you want to keep.

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  function clean(o, h) {
    var results = "";
    if (h == undefined) {
      results = o.text().trim();
    } else {
      $(o).children().each(function(i, el) {
        if (h.indexOf($(el).prop("nodeName").toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
          console.log("Found", $(el).prop("nodeName"));
          results += $(el).prop("outerHTML");
        } else {
          console.log($(el).text().trim());
          results += $(el).text().trim();
        }
      });
    }
    return results;
  }

  $(".className").html(clean($(".className"), ["h1", "br"]));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="className">
  <h1>Something here</h1>
  </br>
  <p>Next line text</p>
</div>
```

There is a pitfall here in that if there is raw text, it might also get stripped away.

Comment: Hmmm, didn't know you could do that, but it still doesn't work with that trim function. See updated code above...

Comment: @Jan what do you see in Console?

Comment: @Jan please clarify what you mean by "*it still doesn't work with that trim function.*"

Comment: sorry... the console doesn't output any text, see updated code above. Thanks

Comment: @Jan you stated that already. I am pretty confident that your issue is here: `const $ = await fetchHTML(thisEntry.link);` If you have no output in Console; then none of your code is running. I don't use Node.js so maybe I am missing something but jQuery uses `$` as part of it's NameSpace and you're assigning a new value to `$`.

Comment: Yes, I think I mixing up ajax with modern JS